# Measuring the amount of data downloaded during a session

Tags: r, session, traffic

Is there a simple way to check the amount of data that was downloaded and/or uploaded via an Internet connection during a single R session?

I have tried to parse `.Rhistory` file where each downloaded file or package is mentioned in the history file. The problem is, when using `checkpoint` package for package reproducibility, the installation of packages goes without an indication of the amount of data downloaded.

I'm sure there must be a better solution than just parse `.Rhistory`. My attempt to find a relevant function using `sos::findFn` was not successful.

Comment: As your question now stands it is way to broad. For starters, you should clarify what you mean with *transferred data*. If you want to discuss this, you could also try the [R Public chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public).

Comment: @Jaap I cannot understand why you consider this question too broad. I clarified it specifying that I am interested in measuring the amount of data transferred via internet connection. The ideal solution I hope for could be just framed in two words: `package::function`. Is that too broad?

Comment: Requesting for solutions of type `package::function` are of topic on SO (Tool request). Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (closing reason #4).

Comment: @DavidArenburg `package::function` would be an **ideal** solution. Otherwise, I would appreciate any indication how to solve my task. Based on the logic that you express, half of the useful answers on SO should be removed as they are mere recommendations which tool to use.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Many of the questions are off topic on SO even if some consider them helpful. In other words, the fact that a question is helpful doesn't make it on topic on this specific site. Either way, I can't really decisively conclude if this specific question is off topic or not, and hence haven't participated in it's closure. Also, maybe add some more information regarding what you already tried, what the issues you encountered, what exactly is not working and what do you consider a "*better solution*".

Comment: @DavidArenburg Ok. May be, you are right. But based on my previous experience, for me SO was not only the resource to find help in "WTF" situations but also the place where you may find a solution of a "how-to" nature. May be, the last is considered off-topic. Yet, there is such a blurred boundary between facing an error and not knowing how to perform a certain task; and half of the questions on SO deal with the latter.

Comment: @DavidArenburg just try "how to" in the SO search, and then please explain what is the main difference between some of the most upvoted questions (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-to-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python)) and mine

Comment: Each of them different. Some of them contain code and what they actually trying/tried to do and specifying what is not working/etc. While others are plain off topic. But most of them are back from 2008-2012; back then everything, was allowed. The rules of the game have changed since then.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Seems so subjective. But thanks a lot for you patient explanations

Comment: As I said, if you will add some information regarding what are you trying to do, what is not working, what have you tried, etc.- it will be probably will be reopened. It is also possible that your question is in a field where not many people are familiar with and hence they consider it's "broad". Adding more information will make the question more readable and target a wider audience that can possibly help.

Comment: Even small edits can your question a lot clearer. Now it is clear what you mean with *transferred data*. Voted to reopen.